# Finding corners of grid and do homography mapping

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, corner-detection

[image]

Hi guys, I would want to find the corners of this calibration card, to enable scaling and geometric calibration. The image above is the grid I am referring to.
Shown is the full image, and I want the corners detected for the black and white grid.
[image]

However, when I try to run

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_cal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #image_cal is the image to be calibrated
cv2_imshow(gray)
retval, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (3, 4))
```

The `retval` returns false, meaning no chessboard is detected.
I have tried different pictures but it seems they all cannot be detected.

Then I turn to Harrison Corner Detection,

```
gray = np.float32(gray)

# bi = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 5, 75, 75)
# blurred = cv2.filter2D(gray,-1,kernel)

dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
dst = cv2.dilate(dst, None)
image_cal[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
cv2_imshow(image_cal)
```

[image]

Which gives me many corners, but I cannot accurately just narrow down to only the black and white grid corners.

Also, there is no guarantee the next image to be fed will still have the black and white grid in the same position so I cannot use some location boundaries to limit the search.

Eventually I would want to know the coordinates of the corners and their corresponding mapped coordinates (such that the target coordinates are properly spaced in distance according to the grid e.g. adjacent vertical or horizontal corners are 1cm apart, without distortion), and feed into a `findHomography` function of opencv.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you able to modify the chart? If yes, add QR Codes (or other well detectable markers) around it

Comment: @Micka I'm not able to modify it unfortunately...